# Google Chrome puts percent sign in all my search queries when new tab is opened

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-search

I have an issue where Google Chrome pre-pends a symbol to my search query when I open a new chrome tab and type a search query in the url bar.

For example. I open a new tab and type in "news" and the query returns with this "%news". Then I have to manually delete the % sign and search again for the keyword. Also, if I type in "d3" it automatically converts that into a "?" symbol and searches google for "?". This issue only happens when I open a new tab and search in the address bar. If I actually go to google.com it does not happen.

Comment: Seems anything inserts a `%` automatically. Does it happen when you disable all extensions, too?

Comment: Voted to migrate to [su]

Comment: @modiX - i actually don't have any extensions downloaded. it's a brand new machine

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong place to ask, but seems like your search engine setting is misconfigured.

See `chrome://settings/searchEngines` and see if your default has `%%s` instead of `%s` in it.